# Applying a dynamic template to multiple types - for managing tokens for sorting

Tags: elasticsearch

We are having some difficulty on figuring out how to best manage our tokenized and untokenized fields for both searching and sorting. Our goals are pretty straightforward:

1. Support Partial word searches
2. Support Sorting on all all fields
3. Our mapping must be dynamic, customers add new fields at runtime.

We're able to accomplish this using a dynamic template. We Store Strings using the default tokenizer, a custom, ngram tokenizer, and an unanalyzed tokenizer. The mapping:

```
curl -XPUT 'http://testServer:9200/test/' -d '{
        "settings": {
            "analysis": {
                "analyzer": {
                    "my_ngram_analyzer": {
                        "tokenizer": "my_ngram_tokenizer",
                        "filter": [
                            "lowercase"
                        ],
                        "type" : "custom"
                    },
                    "default_search": {
                        "tokenizer" : "keyword",
                        "filter" : [
                            "lowercase"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "tokenizer": {
                    "my_ngram_tokenizer": {
                        "type": "nGram",
                        "min_gram": "3",
                        "max_gram": "100",
                        "token_chars": []
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        "mappings": {
            "TestObject": {
                "dynamic_templates": [
                    {
                        "metadata_template": {
                            "match_mapping_type": "string",
                            "path_match": "*",
                            "mapping": {
                                "type": "multi_field",
                                "fields": {
                                    "ngram": {
                                        "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                        "index": "analyzed",
                                        "index_analyzer": "my_ngram_analyzer",
                                        "search_analyzer" : "default_search"
                                    },
                                    "{name}": {
                                        "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                        "index": "analyzed",
                                        "index_analyzer" : "standard",
                                        "search_analyzer" : "default_search"
                                    },
                                    "sortable": {
                                        "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                        "index": "analyzed",
                                        "analyzer" : "default_search"
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }'
```

We're really only keeping the unanalyzed field around for sorting and exact matches (We even call it, 'sortable'. ) This configuration makes it easy for us to get partial word searches, if the query is a "contains" query- we append ".ngram" to the query target. The problem that we are having is deciding when to use the ".sortable" suffix. If the we receive a request to sort on dateUpdated, for example, we don't want to use .sortable, since that field is a date. If The request is to sort on 'name', we do want to use it, since that field is a string, and not use it if we are trying to sort on 'price'.

The logic to check the type of a field before sorting seems a little kludgy (we check in our model, rather than checking the type in elasticsearch).It would be nice to ALWAYS have a '.sortable' field around, but we can't run non-string types through the dynamic template below- booleans and numbers can't be run through an ngram filter.

Does anyone have a suggestion for how we can always have a ".sortable" field for sorting, that would never be tokenized regardless of the type? Or maybe  you have a better solution for this kind of problem that we're not seeing? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What this really boiled down to is that we always wanted to have a "sortable" field- (which we renamed to "unanalyzed" because it has other uses) on *every* mapped field. The real trick to doing this, without adding a new dynamic template for every type, was to make a dynamic template that would be applicable for every type other than a string. To do that, you need to set `match_pattern` to regex:

```
           {
                "other_types": {
                    "match_mapping_type": "date|boolean|double|long|integer",
                    "match_pattern": "regex",
                    "path_match": ".*",
                    "mapping": {
                        "type": "multi_field",
                        "fields": {
                            "{name}": {
                                "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            },
                            "unanalyzed": {
                                "type": "{dynamic_type}",
                                "index": "not_analyzed"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Note that you need to make a small change to "path_match" as well- you have to use a real regular expression (as opposed to '*' which is an ES 'simple' expression.)

The one drawback to this is we are increasing the size of our index- we are storing all of these types twice. For our purposes though, our indexes (we have many) have plenty of room to grow, and it's worth it to avoid having to do a type look up on every field before doing a sort or an exact-match query (just always used ${fieldName}.unanalyzed).

Comment: I realize this is very old but in the current version of Elasticsearch (8.x), regexes do not appear to be supported for `match_mapping_type`. Even when `"match_pattern": "regex"` is specified I get a `mapper_parsing_exception` when I try to provide multiple or'd values like this. I assume this must have worked at some point, given all the upvotes. Strange that they would remove this capability.